# Map function to partial tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the TensorFlow architecture, how do you apply a function to only some elements in a tensor? For example, on the final output of a layer, some variables represent pixel densities which I would like to run through a sigmoid, and a few variables at the beginning of the tensor represent unbounded continuous values, which I would not like to apply an activation function at all.

Here is what I am trying:

```
    output_activation=tf.nn.sigmoid
    x = tf.layers.dense(z, hidden_size, activation=hidden_activation)
    x = tf.layers.dense(x, hidden_size, activation=hidden_activation)
    _logits = tf.layers.dense(x, output_size, activation=None)
    # Apply sigmoid only to image variables
    logits = tf.concat(_logits[:functional_inputs], tf.map_fn(output_activation, _logits[functional_inputs:]), 0)
```

Which is giving the following value error:

```
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("build_decoder/map/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3:0", shape=(?, 288755), dtype=float32)'
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: I think the problem is in `output_activation`, which seems to return a `int32` tensor for the `float32` input. From the documentation of [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn): "Users must provide `dtype` if it is different from the data type of `elems`". So try adding `dtype=tf.int32` to `tf.map_fn`.

Comment: I will give that a shot, thanks

Comment: Hey! I know this is old, but it just saved my day!
Would you mind writing it as an answer if you see this? It might make it easier for others to find :)